# How to shift png

Tags: image, png, edit

My PNG image seems to be shifted down by 1 pixel (compared to what it is supposed to be). I thought this would be an easy fix (to just move the image up by a pixel) except I cant seem to drag it up because there are no extra pixels on the bottom to lose. I can cut away the extra pixel at the top, but then my image is one pixel smaller than it needs to be. My default editor, MS Paint, cant even edit it at all because it is "too small to edit: we cant edit anything smaller than 50 pixels. After about an hour of trying with "Paint 3D" and various online editors I've given up and come here.
If anyone knows any ways to add a row of pixels to the bottom that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can duplicate the last row of pixels in ImageMagick and then append it to the bottom.

Unix syntax:

```
convert image.png \( +clone -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage \) -append new_image.png
```

Windows syntax:

```
convert image.png ( +clone -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage ) -append new_image.png
```

Comment: "Invalid Parameter - ("?

Comment: You have to replace image.png with the name or full path to your actual image. Also be sure to use the appropriate command above if on Windows or Unix-like systems. If on ImageMagick 7, then use magick in place of convert.  What is your ImageMagick version and platform?

Comment: Also be sure you have spaces after the ( and before the )

Comment: Right, my png is called water_bucket so I did replace that, and I did use the windows one. But as for magic, my desktop icon says "ImageMagickDisplay", and when I click it, it brings up a page called IMDesplay that looks like an old timey windows page. did I download the right one?

Comment: No, you did not apparently install ImageMagick. If you did, then you are only using the display viewer.  See https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows. Did you install one of those?

Comment: Yes, i did but I tried to download again just in case and it kept asking whether I wanted to keep or replace existing files. So this is what I typed in my terminal. and the png is on my desktop if that matters: convert water_bucket.png ( +clone -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage ) -append new_water_bucket.png

Comment: Did you change directories to your desktop before issuing the command? What do you get from `convert -version` if you installed ImageMagick 6 or `magick -version` if you installed ImageMagick 7? If they do not work, then ImageMagick is not installed properly. If on Windows, there should be an installer tool. I am not a Windows users, so know little more than that.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by directories,  but the shortcut to the windows thing is on my desktop. But I did all the commands in terminal. When I do the convert version in terminal I get "Invalid drive specification.". When I do the magic version, it shows "ImageMagick 7.1.0-8"

Comment: The try `magick image.png ( +clone -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage ) -append new_image.png` or use magick.exe if necessary in place of magick on Windows. Replace image.png with the name or path to your image file.

Comment: I am on windows and neither of them worked. This is the message that I got exactly copied. "No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3536."

Comment: What did you use to replace image.png? You have to put in your actual image file name (and possibly path to the image if not in your current directory)?  What do you get from `magick -version`?

Comment: Oh, as stated in a previous comment, when I do version I get: "ImageMagick 7.1.0-8" and I use "water_bucket" that is the exact name of the png on my desktop. And I dont know how to use paths.

Comment: Change directories to your desktop. Then from the CMD window type the following `magick water_bucket.png ( +clone -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage ) -append new_water_bucket.png`

Comment: Thank you so much, I eventually figured it out and the command now works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ImageMagick** on Windows, macOS and Linux, in Terminal as follows. I'll use this image with a red, single pixel border.

[image]

---

Chop a row of pixels off the top of an image:

```
magick mogrify -gravity north -chop x1 image.png
```

[image]

---

Chop a row of pixels off the bottom of an image:

```
magick mogrify -gravity south -chop x1 image.png
```

[image]

---

Splice a row of yellow pixels onto top of image:

```
magick mogrify -gravity north -background yellow -splice x1 image.png
```

[image]

---

Splice a row of magenta pixels onto bottom of image:

```
magick mogrify -gravity south -background magenta -splice x1 image.png
```

[image]

---

Just for completeness, chop a column of pixels off the right side:

```
magick mogrify -gravity east -chop 1x image.png
```

[image]

---

And, add a column of cyan pixels to the right side:

```
magick mogrify -gravity east -background cyan -splice 1x image.png
```

[image]

---

Note that all the commands above are done *"in situ"*, which overwrites the input image, and saves you having to specify the same filename for both input and output. It also allows you to use wildcards to specify lots of images, like this:

```
magick mogrify -gravity north -chop x1 *.png *.jpg
```

If, however, you want to avoid overwriting the input image, change from this format:

```
magick mogrify -gravity north -chop x1 image.png
```

to this format which processes a single input image and saves the result under a different name:

```
magick INPUT.PNG -gravity north -chop x1 OUTPUT.PNG
```

Or, if you want to do lots of images at once, i.e. using `mogrify` and wildcards, but do not want to overwrite your original images, you can use `mogrify` and also make and use an output directory:

```
mkdir OUTPUT
magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -gravity north -chop x1 *.png *.jpg
```

---

Note that you can combine any/all of the above, so if you want to start with the original image at the beginning of the answer, and slice a line off the top and add a line of lime green at the bottom:

```
magick image.png -gravity north -chop x1 -gravity south -background lime  -splice x1 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: It didnt work because "unable to open image '<mypng>.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3536